# Already installed mpi4py but Python IDLE fails to import mpi4py.MPI

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am trying to import `mpi4py`. On my MAC terminal, I used the command:

```
pip install mpi4py
```

and it said, `Successfully installed`

But when I try:

```py
from mpi4py import MPI
```

on IDLE, it still says `No module named 'mpi4py'`

Here is the IDLE [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCe2z.png) and the terminal [info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5bqp.jpg)

I have several versions on my Mac including the python downloaded from [python.org](https://python.org/download) and Anaconda.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gxQJ.jpg) is all the coding software I have.

I tried to delete the `anaconda3` folder and run `pip install mpi4py` again. But it doesn't work. It would say `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Can you add more details like, does your system have multiple python versions, example anaconda version and independent version etc

Comment: did you double check your python script uses the `python` interpreter provided by anaconda?